# Getting ,status is 503 in elascticsearch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, configuration, devops

While doing:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

I am getting, status is 503 in elascticsearch.
Please help me to rectify the issue.

```
{
   "status" : 503,
   "name" : "My First Node",
   "cluster_name" : "mycluster1",
   "version" : {
       "number" : "1.7.3",
       "build_hash" : "05d4530971ef0ea46d0f4fa6ee64dbc8df659682",
       "build_timestamp" : "2015-10-15T09:14:17Z",
       "build_snapshot" : false,
       "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
},
   "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/health?v` ?

Comment: Did you check your ES logs ?

Comment: Hi Val, Thanks for your comment, i run the command curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/health?v and below attached the error.

{"error":"MasterNotDiscoveredException[waited for [30s]]","status":503}[

Comment: How many nodes is your cluster made of? Please verify that the java version is same for every one of them. If this don't solve your problem, verify the discovery.zen.* configuration is correct on each node. And verify you have a master eligible node set up. For more detailed support you'll need to provide more infomation (config/logs).